# same ip range and subnet in 2 different bridges

Tags: virtual-machine, bridge, qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt

I am trying to create 2 different virtual networks in the same ip range (not using NAT) in virt manager.Doesn't work with the gui or editing the xml of the new virtual network . Is the best way to create bridges with brctl and configuring the addresses with dnsmasq? Thanks, help would be appreciated.